# AWS Random unhealthy instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, health-monitoring

i have target group that hold around 3-4 servers

starting this week, we start seeing an intermittent unhealthy alarms

[image]

altho it mostly just for 1 instance and very short (1-2 minutes)
any idea why this happened ? where should i start checking whats wrong ? i can confirm that my app didn't crash when the unhealthy event occured

Comment: Nothing in all the logs on the instances themselves at the specific times?

Comment: What health check have you specified?

Answer (score 0):

The metrics simply indicate that the Health Check failed.

You can configure the health check:

- How often to check
- How many failures should cause "Unhealthy"
- How many failures should cause "Healthy" (after a failure)

If you find that the instances are working fine even when they are marked as unhealthy, then you might want to increase the time between checks, or increase the number of check required to mark an instance as Unhealthy.

However, you really should start by investigating whether the application is responding correctly and what might be causing the failed health checks. You could set an alarm for `>0 Unhealthy instances` to signal you when to investigate.